# Cannot send a transaction using Plutus

Tags: plutus, plutus-pab, plutus-starter

I get the following error when I try to send a transaction that locks some ADA in a UTXO:

```
[pab:Warning:41] [2022-01-28 11:58:42.88 UTC] WalletClientError
```

"ConnectionError (HttpExceptionRequest Request {\n  host                 = "localhost"\n  port                 = 8090\n  secure               = False\n  requestHeaders       = [("Accept","application/json;charset=utf-8,application/json"),

("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8")]\n  path                 = "/v2/wallets/70cf045f3e980335f39035b14d6dcc165001bea0/transactions-balance"\n  queryString          = ""\n  method               = "POST"\n  proxy                = Nothing\n  rawBody              = False\n  redirectCount        = 10\n  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault\n  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1\n

proxySecureMode      = ProxySecureWithConnect\n}\n (ConnectionFailure Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 16>: unsupported operation (Cannot assign requested address)))"

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which set up are you using: the VScode container or Nix?

Comment: @Angelo, I'm using VScode container